# Creating new column and Comparison

Tags: mysql, sql

**Table A**

```
    > - Product#   
      11120   
      11121    
     11122
    11123|
****Table B****
      Product# 
         11120   
          11121    
         11122
        11123
      11124

`
```

Trying to create new column and then do comparing? Condition, if the Product# is not fond in Table A then its new Product.

**o/p**

```
product#|NewProduct
  11120 |No
      11121 |NO   
     11122|NO 
    11123|NO 
  11124 |Yes New Product
   -"as it's record is not available  in-table A, hence it will be labelled as new product"
```

Query tried:

```
select 
       A.product#, 
    CASE
    WHEN B.`Product# in (select `Product# from `Table B`)  THEN 'NO'
    ELSE 'Yes'
END AS 'new customer'
FROM Table A`
```

Comment: Why are there two tables for what seems to be the same entity type?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` and  `RIGHT JOIN` combining with `UNION` :

```
SELECT COALESCE(type_a ,type_b) AS type,
       COALESCE(customer_a,customer_b) AS customer, 
       CASE WHEN type_a is null THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS New_Customer
  FROM
  ( 
    SELECT a.type as type_a,a.customer as customer_a, 
           b.type as type_b,b.customer as customer_b
      FROM TableA a
      LEFT JOIN TableB b
        ON a.Customer=b.Customer
     UNION
    SELECT a.type as type_a,a.customer as customer_a, 
           b.type as type_b,b.customer as customer_b
      FROM TableA a
      RIGHT JOIN TableB b
         ON a.Customer=b.Customer
   ) q
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b2c001c68117749cb9cbd4d7a23b9d80)</kbd>

**Update** : Basically, the similar logic is needed for this new case. While in the above we were using `FULL JOIN`,which My SQL DB doesn't have, logic through combining `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN` is enough for this case :

```
SELECT b.`Product#`, 
       CASE WHEN a.`Product#` is null THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS New_Customer
  FROM TableB b
  LEFT JOIN TableA a
    ON a.`Product#`= b.`Product#`;
```

P.S. In the first case, I didn't include `Product#` columns which's not gotta do with the query.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=430ce97ee77c874c71de1370b1b243f4)</kbd>

Comment: I already found exactly the same result with yours and showed in the demo, what's the problem @newtechy ?

Comment: @newtechy If you mean the query in the Demo, I just changed it. Perhaps you're using DB version prior to 8 which doesn't have Common Table Expression.

Comment: I just checekd your demo query. I apologise I was looking at the syntax. I just updated the query. Please help me. I appreciate your help and knowledge .

Answer (score 0):

You need a `LEFT JOIN` of `TableB` to `TableA` and a `CASE` expression which will return the result  that you want:

```
select
  b.Product,
  case when a.Product is null then 'YES' else 'NO' end as `new customer`
from TableB as b left join TableA as a
on b.Product = a.Product
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rjTt4mPNtdu7GyULFJBcXZ/0).
Results:

```
| Product | new customer |
| ------- | ------------ |
| 11120   | NO           |
| 11121   | NO           |
| 11122   | NO           |
| 11123   | NO           |
| 11124   | YES          |
```

Comment: @ forpas its picking the duplicate values. I also added DISTINCT, dont know why its giving me result which is not expected.                                                                
 select DISTINCT 
  b.Product,
  case when a.Product is null then 'YES' else 'NO' end as `new customer`
from TableB as b left join TableA as a
on b.Product = a.Product

Comment: @newtechy it seems that in your actual data there are duplicates. The code in my answer uses the sample data from your question.

Comment: @newtechy if this answer solved your problem consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark.